# Behavior of the external HD and USB drive during hibernation

Tags: hard-drive, usb-flash-drive, hibernate, adobe-acrobat

In Windows 10, I work with pdf files that I keep stored in a USB flash-drive and in an external hard drive. When I put the computer in hibernation I disconnect them both, leaving the pdf files open; I reconnect them before turning on the computer, but then I can continue to read only those of the USB flash-drive, while for those of the external HD Acrobat gives the error "Insufficient data for an image" despite the external HD being connected. How could I fix the external HD problem so that I can continue reading the pdfs even after hibernation?

Comment: This sounds like an intention limitation of Acrobat.

Comment: Both devices are connected via USB. Even if I don't unplug them during hibernation, the same problem arises.

Comment: `intention` was suppose to read `intentional`.  What you describe is a intentional limitation of Acrobat, likely due to the fact, the entire PDF isn't read into memory.

Comment: I understand. In your opinion, why is the pdf from the pendrive read into memory instead? Is there any way to workaround this limitation?

Comment: The ability to read the entire PDF into memory depends on the size of the PDF and the system capability.  As for the reason it wouldn't be read into memory, depending on the size of the PDF (I have created 500 MB PDF that was only a few pages in the past), that is a lot of wasted system memory for an edge case.  Check the options of the unspecified version of Acrobat for something that surrounds this option or simply adjust your workflow (for instance NOT disconnecting the drive with the file open).

Comment: My Acrobat Pro DC version is 2020.009.20065. The problem occurs even if I do not disconnect the Drive with the file open, but ONLY with the external hard disk and NOT with the pendrive. This is very strange and makes me think that it is not an error due to the size of the pdf file (specifically, the SAME pdf file remains open if I open it from the pendrive, but gives the error if opened from the external hard drive)